# How can I navigate away if useLocation()-state is null without loading the page?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

My React project passes data from a component to `FoodDetails` and this works, but I want it to navigate away if the `state` property of `location` from the `useLocation` is null.

Code:

```
const FoodDetails = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  if (location.state === null) {
    navigate("/")
  }

  const food = location.state.food;

  return (
    <div className='FoodDetails'>
      <div className="FoodDetailsName">{food.name}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FoodDetails
```

It goes into the `if`, but it *ignores* the `navigate("/")`. I've placed a return after it and the return works so it just overlooks the navigate.

Why does it ignore it and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention that I have a `useState` hook after the if. I didn't think this will cause an error, but it does.
I tried various ways like placing it above the if(like in the code below) and I also tried to place it above, but not initiate it, but setting the value after the if both didn't work for me.

The first approach is better I think, but I cannot initiate the value , because I get a `TypeError`, because location.state.food.weight is null. The second one creates an `Infinite Loop`.

Code:

```
const FoodDetails = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [weight, setWeight] = useState(location.state.food.weight || 100);
    
    
  if(location.state === null) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className='FoodDetails'>
      <div className="FoodDetailsName">{food.name}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FoodDetails
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the issue with the `useState` hook but please don't make a habit of editing and changing/adding additional issues to the post once answers have been provided as it can change the meaning of the post and invalidate provided answers. It's not fair if existing answers then receive downvotes because the question changed after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `navigate` function issues an imperative navigation action, and the current implementation is calling as an *unintentional* side-effect. While you *could* use a `useEffect` hook to call `navigate` as an *intentional* side-effect, the component still renders first *and then* the `useEffect` hook callback is called. You'd see the returned JSX momentarily.

I would suggest conditionally rendering the [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component instead. It will issue a declarative navigation action during the initial render cycle. The other food details JSX won't have a chance to be rendered.

In either case though the `FoodDetails` component and route/page will be loaded/rendered. This is just a way to mitigate rendering momentary UI that you don't want a user to see.

For setting the initial `weight` state use some Optional Chaining to access into a potentially null or undefined property and nullish coalescing to provide a fallback value. React hooks ***cannot*** be conditionally called, so all hooks necessarily go before ***all*** early returns.

Example:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const FoodDetails = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { food } = state || {};

  const [weight, setWeight] = useState(food?.weight ?? 100);

  if (!food) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className='FoodDetails'>
      <div className="FoodDetailsName">{food.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FoodDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `navigate("/")` inside `useEffect`. Something like:

```
const FoodDetails = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const locationState = location.state;

  useEffect(() => {
    if(locationState === null){
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [locationState]);

  const food = location.state.food;

  return (
    <div className='FoodDetails'>
      <div className="FoodDetailsName">{food.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FoodDetails;
```

`useEffect`'s callback will be run every time something inside its dependency array changes. In this case `locationState`. Note that it's good idea to deconstruct dependencies before `useEffect`.